# Is there a way to disable globbing with the new .NET SDK project system?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am having a lot of performance issues with the new .NET SDK project system. The globbing pattern resolution done by MSBuild is too slow for my directory layout and makes Visual Studio freeze very frequently.

Is there a way to disable the globbing system or is it possible to use ASP.NET Core with the old project system?

Comment: Your only choice is to report to Microsoft with all details you can provide, https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues and hope they can fix it. ASP.NET Core is bind to the new system and there is no way back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable most default globs with this property.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects and https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems for more details

Comment: There seems to be a bug in Visual Studio with the evaluation of certain conditions on property and item groups. I found a workaround myself but will mark your anwser as the correct one. https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2238#issuecomment-316182861